# Error consulta MongoDB promise

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Actualmente estoy trabajando en un proyecto que quedó parado. El problema es que las consultas a la base de datos no funcionan. La base de datos esta operativa y funcionando, recibe querys y las devuelve, pero cada vez que hay una consulta, recibo un error. Creo que el problema es la forma en la que están construidas las querys.

¿Qué error puede haber en esta consulta?

```
const findUser = async email => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    User.findOne(
      {
        email
      },
      'password loginAttempts blockExpires name email role verified verification',
      (err, item) => {
        utils.itemNotFound(err, item, reject, 'USER_DOES_NOT_EXIST')
        resolve(item)
      }
    )
  })
}
```

Al ejecutarse, la promesa se resuelve con error. El valor de `email` no es nulo y existe en la base de datos, por lo que debería de devolver el usuario. La conexión con la base de datos funciona y tiene permisos.

El caso es que existen múltiples consultas escritas de la misma forma, pero ninguna funciona. ¿Puede ser por la versión de node que utilizo? Actualmente utilizo la 14 alpine, pero he probado con otras versiones y sigue sin funcionar.

Gracias de antemano!

Edit:
Debugueando, el error `err` es null

Comment: No necesitas envolver el método de Mongoose en una Promesa para obtener el resultado. Te hace falta validar si el error es `null` o no para manejar el mismo. Tus errores son de lógica y de falta de debug. Saludos

Comment: El método [`findOne`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOne) devuelve una promise. Al usar la sintaxis de `callback`, como ya te señalaron, te esta fallando la lógica. Si `err` es `null` hacer esto, sino, aquello.

Comment: @Marcos, `findOne` no devuelve una Promesa, devuelve un objeto `Query`. Es una confusión bastante común, ya que el objeto `Query` devuelto es `thenable`, pero no es una Promesa.

Comment: @MauricioContreras, tenes razón ^^

Answer (score 0):

**PROBLEMA**

Tal como digo en [mi comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/536669/error-consulta-mongodb-promise?noredirect=1#comment950748_536669), no necesitas envolver [el método `findOne`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOne) dentro de una [Promesa](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). Pero no es porque el mismo devualva una Promesa, devuelve un objeto de [tipo `Query`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/query.html) que es un tipo de Objeto `thenable` (es decir que implementa `then`) y que además puede ser usado con `await`.

Por otro lado, no estás manejando realmente el posible error que pueda arrojar tu consulta en caso de que lo hubiera. Es por ello que el comportamiento de tu aplicación no es el esperado.

**SOLUCIÓN**

Lo primero es entender lo que sucede en una consulta a MongoDB usando el metodo `findOne` de [Mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/).

Cuando usas el método `findOne` tienes 3 alternativas:

1. usar una función *callback*
2. usar *await* (dentro de un entorno *async*)
3. usar *then* y *catch*

Lo que no puedes hacer es mezclar alegremente las 3, a menos que estés totalmente seguro de cómo hacerlo.

Suponiendo que no tienes una necesidad de mezclar los 3 métodos anteriores, vamos a ver cómo escribir correctamente tu función usando `async/await`, ya que es lo que parece más apropiado viendo tu código.

**Usando `async/await`**

[Una llamada a una función tipo `async` devuelve una Promesa](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function#descripci%C3%B3n), por lo tanto decir esto es totalmente redundante:

```js
async myAsyncMethod(arg) {
  return new Promise( ... )
}
```

Por otro lado, ya dijimos que el método `findOne` devuelve un Objeto tipo `Query` y aunque es válido usar `await` sobre el mismo, lo ideal es poder trabajar con una Promesa. El usar un Objeto de tipo `Query` es válido en muchos otros escenarios, pero en este caso tan sencillo podemos usar directamente una Promesa en vez del Objeto `Query`. Para ello, el mismo Objeto nos provee de un método que sí devuelve una Promesa, este método se llama [`exec`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/query.html#query_Query-exec) y lo podemos encadenar al llamado a `findOne` (o a cualquier otra *query* de Mongoose). Esto es muy importante, ya que [las *queries* no son Promesas](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html#queries-are-not-promises), pero podemos obtener una al usar `exec`.

Reescribiendo tu código para usar ahora sí una Promesa se vería algo así:

```js
const findUser = async email => {
  const project = 'password loginAttempts blockExpires name email role verified verification';
  const user = await User.findOne({ email }, project).exec();
  // ...
}
```

Luego falta manejar el error, y esto lo haremos manejando la resolución o el rechazo de la Promesa devuelta por `exec`. Cuando trabajamos con Promesas debemos siempre manejar los 2 posibles casos: Resolución o Rechazo. Una forma de hacerlo es usando un bloque `try ... catch`, por ejemplo:

```js
const findUser = async email => {
  const project = 'password loginAttempts blockExpires name email role verified verification';
  try {
    const user = await User.findOne({ email }, project).exec();
    // ... hacemos cosas con user
  }
  catch(err) {
    // manejamos el error
  }
}
```

Por último, debemos recordar que una consulta a MongoDB mediante `findOne` puede devolvernos un documento, un valor `null` o resultar en error. Ya vimos que es fácil manejar el error usando `try ... catch`, y podemos decir tu función devuelve directamente un usuario si es conseguido en la DB o `null` en caso contrario:

```js
const findUser = async email => {
  const project = 'password loginAttempts blockExpires name email role verified verification';
  try {
    const user = await User.findOne({ email }, project).exec();
    // muestro logs o hago otras cosas con user
    if(!user) {
      console.warn('USER_DOES_NOT_EXIST');
    }
    return user;
  }
  catch(err) {
    // manejamos el error
    console.error(err.message);
    return null;
  }
}
```

Como se aprecia, tanto cuando la Promesa se resuelve o se rechaza se devuelve un valor. Para el caso de error se devuelve `null` y se muestra por consola el mensaje de error. Y si la Promesa es resuelta, sólo se muestra el mensaje de usuario no encontrado si la respuesta de `findOne` es nula. Finalmente se devuelve el valor que tenga `user`, que puede ser un documento de la DB o simplemente `null`.

No comprendo exactamente lo que hace tu función utilitaria `utils.itemNotFound(err, item, reject, 'USER_DOES_NOT_EXIST')`, pero no lo veo muy apropiada, ya que estás mezclando en la misma un error de la llamada a `findOne` con la posibilidad de que un usario no exista. Toma en cuenta que son 2 situaciones muy diferentes.

Un error se produce cuando la consulta no se ha podido realizar correctamente. En estos casos se dice que es un error del Servidor (un error tuyo o de tu servicio y no del cliente) por lo cual, en este escenario, la respuesta al cliente debería tener una cabecera con estado http 5xx.

Cuando un usuario no existe en la DB, significa que la consulta se realizó correctamente (no hubo error en la petición a la DB), por lo cual el mensaje devuelto al cliente puede contener una cabecera de estado http 404 (*Not Found*) o 200 (Ok) (esto ya dependerá de lo que estás realmente haciendo).

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.